# Segmentation Fault (core dumped): Error when providing no argument

Tags: segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, argv, coredump, argc

[Code implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uW0p.png)  I was trying to implement the code such way that it takes only a command line argument, and if not provided or provided more than 1, it prints out an error message. But it is showing "segmentation fault(core dumped)" whenever I am not giving any argument in the command line. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings -- `int main` is supposed to return something. That said, there is no way for the code you show to die with segmentation fault -- something is wrong with your environment.